# Определение типов файлов в С

Tags: c++, c

код который выводит список файлов

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
int main (void) {
     DIR *dir;
     struct dirent *ent;
     char directory[255] = "./";
     dir = opendir(directory);
     while ((ent=readdir(dir)) != NULL){
        printf("%s\n", ent->d_name);
     }
     closedir(dir);
     return 0;}
```

компилирую

```
user@user-pc$ ./a.out //выполняю программу и получаю список файлов   
text1.txt<----------------------------------------ненужен  
картинка_1.jpg<------------------------------НУЖЕН  
text2.txt<----------------------------------------ненужен  
картинка2.jpeg<------------------------------НУЖЕН  
book1.pdf<--------------------------------------ненужен  
красивая картинка.bmp<-----------------НУЖЕН  
музыка.mp3<----------------------------------ненужен  
очень красивая картинка.JPG<-------НУЖЕН  
многобукв.doc<------------------------------ненужен  
опять картинка.TIFF<----------------------НУЖЕН
```

ТО ЕСТЬ мне нужно
Выбрать из папки с разными файлами, только те файлы, которые относятся к изображениям(типу).

```
user@user-pc$ ./a.out //выполняю программу  
картинка_1.jpg<------------------------------НУЖЕН  
картинка2.jpeg<------------------------------НУЖЕН  
красивая картинка.bmp<-----------------НУЖЕН   
очень красивая картинка.JPG<--------НУЖЕН   
опять картинка.TIFF<----------------------НУЖЕН
```

КАК???ЧЕМ???

Comment: Проверять расширение файла пробовали?
jpg, jpeg, bmp, tiff

Comment: Может вам поможет эта статья http://habrahabr.ru/post/186828/

Comment: Смотря что подразумевается под "типом". Если просто последние буковки в имени, то смотреть в сторону fnmatch()

Comment: fnmatch() принимает монжественные значения?

Comment: fnmatch("@(*.jpg|*.jpeg|*.tiff)", file, FNM_EXTMATCH|FNM_CASEFOLD);

Comment: Только не забудьте

    #define _GNU_SOURCE

перед

    #include <fnmatch.h>

а то не скомпилируется

Comment: А у меня без _GNU_SOURCE проходит...

`gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3`

Comment: Спасибо! Я так побывал но чего-то не пошло(попробую еще). 
А может  правильнее считать тип файла?

Comment: Правильное определение - это [утилита file](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=file&category=1&russian=5)

    [13:46:30] klopp:dev $ file a.out 
    a.out: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x64289845fcbec367de90e2c6ff49f7eb818e461a, not stripped
    
    [13:49:45] klopp:dev $ file 1.pl 
    1.pl: Perl script, UTF-8 Unicode text executable
    
    [13:50:33] klopp:dev $ file cartman.mp3 
    cartman.mp3: MPEG ADTS, layer III, v2, 128 kbps, 22.05 kHz, JntStereo

Comment: @klopp, новое (gcc 4.7.3) это наверное (может быть) хорошо, но с той же Ubuntu стандартно идет (и пока автоматом не обновляется) 4.6.3, а в RHEL стоит 4.4.4, а у многих клиентов хорошо, если вообще 4-ка.

Так что надежнее писать под что-то устоявшееся (во избежании проблем, что Вы у себя собрали, а у заказчика таких версий .so нет и из исходника не собирается).

Comment: И как все таки лучше сделать??? фильтровать по разрешению файла или по типу???

Comment: @avp, с Ubuntu 13.10 уже автоматом идет gcc 4.8

Comment: @Jonik908, все завистт от того, что Вы собираетесь делать дальше с отобранными файлами.